# tense agreement (the simple past tense and the past perfect tense)

Tags: tense-agreement

I found this sentence below in a test passage:

> He had only become a dog-lover in later life when Jofi was given to him by his daughter Anna.

Why is "Jofi was" used when the tense of the main clause is the past perfect tense?

Comment: More to the point: why is the past perfect used? Depending on the wider context, of course, it would be possible to use the past tense in the main part of the sentence: "He only become a dog-lover in later life when Jofi was given to him by his daughter Anna".

Comment: Sentences do not always have to maintain the same tense throughout. Some sentences, which are grammatical, use very different tenses.

Comment: @BillJ  The previous sentence is this: Less well known at the time was the fact that Freud had found out, almost by accident, how helpful his pet dog Jofi was to his patients.